# Listen for changes to an object in a Redisson Object Holder (RBucket)?

Tags: java, redisson

The RBucket class offers:

```
addListener(ObjectListener listener)
```

I tried to use this method but as far as I can tell, I could only listen for when an object is deleted (DeletedObjectListener) or expired (ExpiredObjectListener). Is it possible to listen to changes to an object in an RBucket?

Answer (score 1):

Redisson allows to track set event of `RBucket` object. Here is the code example:

```
RBucket<String> bucket = redisson.getBucket("myBucket");  
bucket.addListener(new SetObjectListener() {  
    public void onSet(String name) {  
        // ...  
    }  
});
```